# doesn't deduce the response from the IE9 server but if I turn on in it the console that all ok

Tags: jquery, ajax, browser

Google Chrome and Firefox deduces the response from the server without problems why doesn't deduce the response from the IE9 server but if I turn on in it the console that all ok

jquery

```
var cur_numbquest = 0;

function answer(numquest, idvar, idquest){
    $('#quest_'+numquest).fadeOut(200, function(){
        if (cur_numbquest>=countquest) {
            $("#finishtest").fadeIn(200);
        } else {
            $('#quest_'+(numquest+1)).fadeIn(200);
        }
    });
    //quests[temp_number_quest]['id_quest'] = temp_id_quest;
    quests[numquest]['id_var'] = idvar;
    console.log("Text, example N="+numquest+", "+idvar+", "+idquest);
cur_numbquest++;
var post_data = JSON.stringify(quests);

if (cur_numbquest>=countquest){
        var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/wp-content/plugins/votefe/www/php/ajax/addanswer.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data: "quests=" + post_data,
        success: function(response)
    {
            for (var i=0;i<3;i++){
            var html = response[i][0] + "<br />";
            $("#finishtest").append(html);
            } 
    }
    });
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if to whom interesting that response deleting this line

console.log("Text, example N="+numquest+", "+idvar+", "+idquest);